# Can you apply a manually defined schema when you try to read delta files in databricks?

Tags: schema, databricks, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

I have created a manual schema by using structtype etc.

I have a silver level 1 layer in ALDS containing raw delta files. I need to apply the manual schema to this silver level 1 layer which will then be written back as silver level 2. So I simply need to read in the SL1 data apply the manual schema and then write it to SL2

I get the following error when I try to read in the data from SL1:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: DeltaDataSource source does not support user-specified schema.`

Does anyone know how to proceed? Below the code I used to read in the delta files.

`vbak = spark.read.format(read_format).schema(vbak_schema).load(load_path)`

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: I have one use case, where I want to refer to other delta schema rather then reading and casting column by column